# Interligar 3 tabelas sql entre si, utilizando INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, antes de eu tentar caprichar em PHP mais a fundo, ando estudando melhor a logica do mySQL, com select, delete,insert etc. Mas na hora que estudar o banco de dados sql com o tempo, percebi que na prática não é correto inserir todas os elementos em uma tabela só, já que causa uma bagunça na lógica. E então estou nesse impasse tentando entender essa lógica.

Exemplo, tenho 3 tabelas... Uma é "Pessoa", "Profissao" e "Universidade", que ao inves de colocar profissao e universidade dentro da propria tabela Pessoa, resolvi separá-los p/ tentar entender o funcionamento entre si através da interligação entre as 3 tabelas. Sendo que conseguiria conectar a tabela profissão e universidade para Pessoa, problema que não estou conseguindo, e não quero ficar fazendo gambiarras. Como eu faria para inserir um elemento de uma tabela em outra ? Estou colocando um link dos arquivos p/ você tentar entender de acordo com o formulario que fiz, de forma separada...

[LINK DOS ARQUIVOS] [1]: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HxMz4WRrPfAa-X153rxZOOQntpgGk2C4?usp=sharing

Demonstração: (Ou segue, o arquivos que deixei no link, para poder entender melhor, é simples de entender)

```
public function addPessoa($nome, $sobrenome, $telefone) {
    global $pdo;

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pessoa SET nome = :nome, sobrenome = :sobrenome, telefone = :telefone");
    $sql->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
    $sql->bindValue(":sobrenome", $sobrenome);
    $sql->bindValue(":telefone", $telefone);

    $sql->execute();
}


public function addProfissao($nome) {// como eu faria para inserir o nome da universidade da tabela Profissão para tabela Pessoa ?
    global $pdo;

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO profissao SET nome = :nome");
    $sql->bindValue(":nome", $nome);

    $sql->execute();
}


public function addUniversidade($nome) { // como eu faria para inserir o nome da universidade da tabela Universidade para tabela Pessoa ?
    global $pdo;

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO universidade SET nome = :nome");
    $sql->bindValue(":nome", $nome);

    $sql->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Vou tentar esclarecer algumas coisas para você de `SQL`.

1. Você fez certo em criar as tabelas separadas.
2. Você deve colocar o campo que tem a referência de outra tabela ([Chave Estrangeira](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp#:%7E:text=A%20FOREIGN%20KEY%20is%20a,the%20referenced%20or%20parent%20table.)), na **tabela principal**, no caso na tabela "pessoas".

Resumidamente, a "`Chave estrangeira`" ou "`Foreign Key`" serve para você relacionar as suas tabelas, elas vão "conversar" uma com a outra, elas ajudam a você *não inserir* dados incorretos em seu banco de dados, ajuda em uma análise futura caso precise, e também deixa  mais estruturado/elaborado.

Na prática, o seu **SQL** da maneira correta:

```
CREATE TABLE profissao (
  id_profissao int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  nome_profissao varchar(45) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE universidade (
  id_universidade int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  nome_universidade varchar(45) NOT NULL
);

-- Por ultímo a tabela principal, para não gerar conflitos na hora da criação.
-- Pois os campos "fk" estão se referindo a campo de outra tabela.  

CREATE TABLE pessoa (
  id_pessoa int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  nome varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  sobrenome varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  telefone varchar(45) NOT NULL,

  -- Criando chaves estrangeiras
  fk_profissao INT(5),
  foreign key (fk_profissao ) references profissao(id_profissao),

  fk_universidade INT(5),
  foreign key (fk_universidade ) references universidade(id_universidade)
);
```

Após a criação da tabelas, você faz a inserção de dados, como você fez o seu.

Eles devem ter algum *ID* que você tenha criado, na tabela "`profissao`" e "`universidade`", caso contrário, o próprio banco de dados, irá mostrar o erro, pois eles estão referenciados.

3. Após as inserções, você consegue realizar consultas, utilizando
   [JOINS](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-join-entenda-como-funciona-o-retorno-dos-dados/31006).

```
SELECT A.id_pessoa, A.nome, A.sobrenome, A.telefone, B.nome_profissao, C.nome_universidade
FROM pessoa A 
JOIN profissao B ON A.fk_profissao = B.id_profissao
JOIN universidade C ON A.fk_universidade = C.id_universidade;
```

Caso tenha alguma dúvida, pode perguntar, não tem problema algum nisso, espero que tenha ajudado.

**UPDATE:**
Agora, respondendo as perguntas do seu code.

// como eu faria para inserir o nome da universidade da tabela Profissão para tabela Pessoa ?

// como eu faria para inserir o nome da universidade da tabela Universidade para tabela Pessoa ?

**R:** Simples e fácil, você não irá inserir o nome da universidade ou o nome da profissão, você irá inserir o `ID` delas, com o `ID` salvo na tabela, você consegue trazer o nome dela, entendeu?

> Primeiramente, você deve refazer a estrutura do seu banco de dados,
> como eu mostrei acima.

Comment: Caso não tenha entendido, faça as perguntas por aqui, obrigado.

Comment: Samuel, primeiramente obrigado pela explicação objetiva com mysql com a chave estrangeira. Mas como ficaria encaixado com as minhas lógica PHP que deixei, sendo que existe agora uma chave estrangeira... Na parte do "public function addProfissao() e "function addUniversidade" para "addPessoa()" ?

Comment: Cara, seu code php não vai mudar, você só precisa adicionar o campo "fk_profissao" e "fk_universidade" no seu `INSERT INTO pessoa`, simples... reforçando mais uma vez, que o valor desse dois campos que a gente criou, deve ser de tipo `INT`, e ele deve ser o `ID` das outras duas tabelas...

Comment: Pode manter o INSERT profissao e universidade, só precisa alterar o INSERT da tabela pessoa... Exemplo `INSERT INTO pessoa SET nome = 'Kleber', sobrenome = 'Souza', telefone = '40028922', fk_profissao = '1', fk_universidade = '2';`

Comment: Só que tem uma coisa, as paginas php que criei com os formularios, cada um possui só os campos de index.php(PESSOA), profissao.php(PROFISSAO) e universidade.php(UNIVERSIDADE), ou seja, paginas separadas de uma da outra. Não é um formulário numa página só não, Aqui o prints: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ii28eDf_7qCVO5X39EcBuqME8rfeBxoc?usp=sharing

Comment: Nesse caso, você pode adicionar os 2 campos no formulário pessoa... Pode criar 2 selects puxando direto da tabela "profissao" e "universidade", seria isso que você precisa?

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do @Samuel Verissimo, já resolve a questão. Você precisa de um "link" entre uma tabela e outra, e isso é feito usando o Foreign Key.

---

Se você sabe com o foreign key funciona, o que o @Samuel Verissimo explicou, então basta aplica-lo em seu código do PHP, basicamente você deve utilizar o `->lastInsertId();` como documentado em https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php.

Portanto, pelo que parece teria que fazer algo como:

```
public function addPessoa($nome, $sobrenome, $telefone, $id_p, $id_u) : int {
    global $pdo;

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pessoa SET nome = :nome, sobrenome = :sobrenome, telefone = :telefone, profissao = :id_p, universidade = :id_u");
    $sql->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
    $sql->bindValue(":sobrenome", $sobrenome);
    $sql->bindValue(":telefone", $telefone);
    $sql->bindValue(":id_p", $id_p);
    $sql->bindValue(":id_u", $id_u);

    $sql->execute();

    return $sql->lastInsertId();
}


public function addProfissao($nome) : int {
    global $pdo;

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO profissao SET nome = :nome");
    $sql->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
    $sql->bindValue(":id", $id);

    $sql->execute();

    return $sql->lastInsertId();
}


public function addUniversidade($nome) : int {
    global $pdo;

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO universidade SET nome = :nome");
    $sql->bindValue(":nome", $nome);

    $sql->execute();

    return $sql->lastInsertId();
}
```

Dessa forma ao chamar o `addProfissaoa` retornará o `id` a profissão recém criada. Você também deve verificar se a profissão já não existe e retornar possíveis erros, já que caso contrário retornará `id = 0`. Isso funciona assumindo que tenha um AUTO_INCREMENT.

---

Eu recomendaria criar uma Transaction, usando `beginTransaction();` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php). Afinal, imagine que uma profissão seja inserida, mas a inserção do usuário venha a falhar?! Nestes caso é importante que consiga dar um `rollback` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php), cancelando todas as inserções feitas.

Comment: É, vou tentar estudar direito isso. É pq meu prof não explicou de forma objetiva sobre essas chaves estrangeiras do mysql juntamente com o codigo php. Explicou de uma forma mt simples, que de tanto falar e falar, não explicou nada que só criou confusão rs. Vou procurar uns codigos em githubs p/ tentar entender. Obrigado a vocês!